# Why is the QGIS 2.10 raster clip function not working correctly?

Tags: qgis, clip

I am using QGIS 2.10 and everything seems to work just fine so far, except for the raster clipping function (Raster>Extraction>Clipper). I'm using a vector poligon as a mask layer, but after launching the function, it just does nothing - not even showing an error.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @EmīlsKo! Are both raster and vector layers in the same CRS?

Comment: Thak you, Joseph! Yes, they are in the same CRS and the vector layer clearly overlays the raster.

Comment: This function takes sometimes a lot of time to complete (without any feedback from the UI). Did you have a look at CPU usage to check if a QGIS-related process is running?

Comment: what is the size of your clipping area? what is your raster's resolution? If you are saving the result as a flat file .tif, you can browse that folder and check if there's any writing going on, and if the result is increasing in size, i.e. the tool is running